# Icon with 2 paths (colors) in Component.js in Ui5

Tags: sapui5

I have to add an icon from icomoon to Component.js in my Ui5 application. This icon has 2 colors. For some reason it shows only one color of the icon and other color is never shown. I think it is because I should give 2 paths for it. 
one color path is e925 and for other color is e926. How should I assign the other path too?

Component.js

```
IconPool.addIcon("icon-Components", "abcproject", {
                fontFamily: "icomoon",
                content: "e925"
            });
```

Comment: the icon should be in the original color if you just don't specify any color, try that

Comment: but why do you need a icon in the component?

Comment: all icons are declared here in my case, so I am adding one more icon in Component only

Comment: normally you should try to stick to sap icons https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/iconExplorer/webapp/index.html#/overview/SAP-icons/?, if you still need others you should declare them in your manifest under "sap.ui"